# iOS CoreBluetooth not scanning for services in iPad Air

Tags: ios, ipad, core-bluetooth

I'm working on a app that connects to a BLE peripheral and receives data from it.

It scans for peripherals, finds a peripheral, discovers services, and if the right service is found, it receives data.

It works great on an iPhone 5, but when I run it on an iPad Air it connects , but doesn't discover any services, and receives no data. Both devices run iOS 7.0.4

This is some of the relevant parts of the code

```
- (void)startScan
{

    [manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
}

- (void)stopScan
{
    [manager stopScan];
}



- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral    *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
NSLog(@"Did discover peripheral. peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, id: %@ advertisementData: %@ ", peripheral, RSSI, peripheral.identifier, advertisementData);

    if(![self.dicoveredPeripherals containsObject:peripheral])
        [self.dicoveredPeripherals addObject:peripheral];

    [manager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)peripheral.identifier]];

    [manager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:   [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey]];
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
{
    NSLog(@"Retrieved peripheral: %lu - %@", (unsigned long)[peripherals count], peripherals);
    [self stopScan];

    /* If there are any known devices, automatically connect to it.*/
    if([peripherals count] >= 1)
    {
        testPeripheral = [peripherals objectAtIndex:0];

        [manager connectPeripheral:testPeripheral
                       options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey]];
    }
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"Did connect to peripheral: %@", peripheral);
    [self.delegate statusMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did connect to peripheral: %@\n", peripheral]];

    [peripheral setDelegate:self];
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
}


- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        NSLog(@"discovered service [%@]",service.UUID);
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
}
```

The log output on the iPhone 5 is :

```
Did discover peripheral. peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x14587320 identifier = 3EE10DD6-99CD-  7E9C-C492-087CE3B980E6, Name = "BLE Sens", state = disconnected> rssi: -53, id:     <__NSConcreteUUID 0x145f82f0> 3EE10DD6-99CD-7E9C-C492-087CE3B980E6 advertisementData: {
kCBAdvDataChannel = 38;
kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
kCBAdvDataLocalName = BLESensor;
kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
    "Unknown (<fff0>)"
);
kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 0;
} 

Did connect to peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x14587320 identifier = 3EE10DD6-99CD-7E9C-C492-087CE3B980E6, Name = "BLE Sens", state = connected>

Connected
discovered service [Device Information]
discovered service [Unknown (<fff0>)]
discovered service [Unknown (<ffe0>)]
Service found with UUID: Device Information
```

On the iPadAir it just gets to the connected part and no services are found :

```
Did discover peripheral. peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x1700a1440 identifier = 23890BB4-FB07-AA1A-8D4F-B1427C859447, Name = "BLE Sens", state = disconnected> rssi: -60, id:   <__NSConcreteUUID 0x17802f740> 23890BB4-FB07-AA1A-8D4F-B1427C859447 advertisementData: {
    kCBAdvDataChannel = 39;
kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
kCBAdvDataLocalName = BLESensor;
kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
    "Unknown (<fff0>)"
);
kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 0;
} 

Did connect to peripheral: <CBPeripheral: 0x1700a1440 identifier = 23890BB4-FB07-AA1A-8D4F-B1427C859447, Name = "BLE Sens", state = connected>
 Connected
```

Comment: Try with LightBlue.app to see if you can discover services. If not, your might have to reboot the iPad and the BLE Device.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the LightBlue app. On the iPhone the LightBlue app finds the services, but on the iPad air it's "Discovering Services" indefinitely. Same as my app. Reboot doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug. You should go ahead and submit a radar to Apple. http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Did you reset the BLE device? Reboot (iDevice & Device) and/or reset BLE Device is the only solution I got when I got stucked like you sometimes. I couldn't identify what was provoking this.

Comment: Yes, I did reset the BLE device and the iOS device.

Comment: I submitted a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple admitted that this was an issue in iOS 7.0 . They promised to solve it in iOS 7.1. I tested it with iOS 7.1 , and it is solved.

Comment: I am still seeing this issue with 7.1.2